# Overlay transparent window on windows form PictureBox

Tags: winforms, overlay, transparency

I have windows form `PictureBox Control1` that displays video. I would like to create a transparent overlay `Control2` that displays text over the video window.

I tried creating Control2 with BackgroundColor and TransparencyKey set to the same color, ex Color. Green, and adding it to Control1, but the second window just obscures the first one.

Spent the day looking for code that works, but no luck so far.

Comment: Have you tried with a transparent Form (setting `TransparencyKey = BackColor`)? You can paint on it the text you need. Or even use a Label.

Comment: If it is for OS >= Windows 8, you can use layered child windows. For example : [Test transparent label](https://i.ibb.co/Bt4GVnZ/Transparent-Label.gif)